# Select JSON from SQL and JOIN elements by IDs

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

Question: how do I return a row for each question/answer pair? I feel like I almost had it at one point but the nested IDs in the answer threw me off because I was trying Regex, but I imagine there's a more pure play JSON way to do this without any Regex right?

Here's what I'm looking for:

```
i.e.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Question                                      Answer
What do you think?                            Love it. So easy to use.
Which sales channels do you use?              Facebook / Instagram
Scale of 1 to 10  how much do you like this?  7
```

Here's the data:

```
# setup our data
WITH survey_results -- table name
AS
(
    SELECT '''
    {
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": "ycq4WbK9EdNF",
          "title": "What do you think?",
          "type": "long_text"
        },
        {
          "id": "uPLaLxMKZ9lm",
          "title": "Scale of 1 to 10 how much do you like this?",
          "type": "opinion_scale"
        },
        {
          "choices": [
            {
              "id": "k4227hvYbTaR",
              "label": "eBay"
            },
            {
              "id": "zjWplAMROVuP",
              "label": "Etsy"
            }
          ],
          "id": "f6ois7aPxVz4",
          "title": "Which sales channels do you use?",
          "type": "multiple_choice"
        }
      ],
      "id": "k56nsh",
      "title": "Amazon Survey"
    }
    '''
    AS questions, --- column name
    '''
    [
      {
        "field": {
          "id": "ycq4WbK9EdNF",
          "type": "long_text"
        },
        "text": "Love it. So easy to use.",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "field": {
          "id": "uPLaLxMKZ9lm",
          "type": "opinion_scale"
        },
        "number": 7,
        "type": "number"
      },
      {
        "choice": {
          "label": "Facebook / Instagram"
        },
        "field": {
          "id": "f6ois7aPxVz4",
          "type": "multiple_choice"
        },
        "type": "choice"
      }
    ]
    '''
    AS answers --- column name
    )

# run the query

SELECT * from survey_results
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_EXTRACT_QUESTIONS(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<id STRING, question STRING>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try { var parsed = JSON.parse(json).fields; var result = []; 
    for (i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
      e = []; e.id = parsed[i].id; e.question = parsed[i].title; result.push(e);
    }; return result; } catch (e) { return null }
""";
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_EXTRACT_ANSWERS(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<id STRING, answer STRING>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try { var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
    var result = []; for (i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
      e = []; e.id = parsed[i].field.id; 
      e.answer = parsed[i].text || parsed[i].number || parsed[i].choice.label; result.push(e);
    }; return result; } catch (e) { return null }
""";
SELECT q.id, question, answer
FROM survey_results, 
UNNEST(CUSTOM_EXTRACT_QUESTIONS(questions)) q,
UNNEST(CUSTOM_EXTRACT_ANSWERS(answers)) a
WHERE q.id  = a.id
```

if applied against dummy data in your question - result is (tested)

```
Row id              question                                       answer    
1   ycq4WbK9EdNF    What do you think?                             Love it. So easy to use.
2   uPLaLxMKZ9lm    Scale of 1 to 10 how much do you like this?    7
3   f6ois7aPxVz4    Which sales channels do you use?               Facebook / Instagram
```

Comment: Also, quite complicated. Would it be simpler if we uncheck Standard SQL?

Comment: hit a blocker: need this to be exposed in Data Studio, so I tried saving this query as a View. But views don't support temporary functions. How would you suggest that I solve this? I also tried in data studio creating a custom query, but looks like others ran into the same error I did: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Data-Studio/Unexpected-keyword-CREATE-Error/td-p/1588687#

Comment: if you will post new question with new requirements to be able to save as a view etc. - I will most likely answer it. but you will also need to re-accept above answer - as it fully answers your original question :o)